# Restarting CursorLoader does not reflect database deletion

Tags: android, database, android-cursorloader

I am using a CursorLoader to keep track of data in a database. This database can be deleted with

```
Context.deleteDatabase(databaseName);
```

After the deletion I restart the loader with

```
getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
```

Now when I get the callback

```
onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data)
```

it doesn't reflect that the data is gone. I get the same data as before.

Am I doing something conceptually wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The LoaderManager is trying to be smart and re-use the loader.  This is a work-around to a different loader bug, but I think it would work for this:

```
    Loader<Object> loader = getLoaderManager().getLoader(0);
    if (loader != null && ! loader.isReset()) {
        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, mItemsListener);
    } else {
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, mItemsListener);
    }
```